# Remove Object have same property value from Array object when input is Array of property value Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arrayobject

I have array objects:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        name: ABC,
        age: 10
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: ABCXYZ,
        age: 20
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: ZYXCNA,
        age: 30
    },
    ...
    ...
    ....more
]
```

and array is value of `id` in above array object:
`[ 1, 2]`

then i want a array objects not have value of `id` in above array objects.
Ex: Array objects i will receive in here is

```
[
    {
        id: 3,
        name: ZYXCNA,
        age: 30
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: ABCDX,
        age: 30
    }
]
```

i have using 3 for loop in here to slove this problem but i think that can have smarter way.
Like using `reduce` in here, but i still not resolved. Can anyone help me? Thanks so much.

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter] array filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `Array.filter` & `Array.includes`.

```js
const source = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'ABC',
        age: 10
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'ABCXYZ',
        age: 20
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'ZYXCNA',
        age: 30
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'ABCDX',
        age: 30
    }
];

const input = [ 1, 2 ];

const output = source.filter(({ id }) => !input.includes(id));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yo don't need any explicit loops at all, you're just filtering

```js
var input = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "ABC",
        age: 10
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: "ABCXYZ",
        age: 20
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "ZYXCNA",
        age: 30
    },
];

var ids = [1,2];

var result = input.filter(x => ! ids.includes(x.id));
console.log(result);
```